# ¿Cuándo y dónde fue común decir "a las ocho y tres cuartos"? ¿Se sigue diciendo así en alguna parte?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, historia, tiempo

El otro día, mientras trasteaba en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España, me topé con un sinfín de artículos que mencionaban las horas en la forma "y tres cuartos" en vez del actual "menos cuarto". Así, leo:

> Se disolvió la junta á las ocho y tres cuartos.

Hoy día lo normal habría sido decir "a las nueve menos cuarto" o "a las ocho y cuarenta y cinco". El texto citado es de 1830 y es de México, pero igualmente se leen textos así en diarios españoles de la época (siglo XIX). También encuentro algunos (pocos) casos en periódicos argentinos de principios del siglo XX.

Así que ya por curiosidad me asaltan unas cuantas dudas. ¿En qué época y ámbito geográfico fue comun decir "y tres cuartos" en vez de "menos cuarto"? ¿Es esto práctica común hoy día en alguna parte?

Answer (score 2):

Son modas, sobre todo relacionadas con dar pompa a los textos legales o administrativos. Esa forma sigue siendo correcta y por ejemplo en la zona donde yo vivo (Castilla y León, España) puede y suele ser usada por gente mayor, y aunque podría considerarse ligeramente arcaica, coloquialmente no causa sorpresa.

Comment: Recuerdo esa expresión en Colombia en los años 1970 y 1980, pero con el uso de los computadores está lentamente pasando a desuso las expresiones "y cuarto", "y media", "falta un cuarto" siendo reemplazadas por la expresión de los minutos.

Answer (score 2):

En México aun sigue siendo común usar

> ocho y tres cuartos

sin embargo es una manera algo informal de decirlo, no lo verías hoy en día en un escrito formal, en su lugar se utiliza el término con su notación en minutos:

> a las ocho cuarenta y cinco

además se utilizan variantes como:

> a las ocho y cuarto (8:15)

o

> cuarto para las 8 (7:45)